# storyboard safe area landscape mode

Tags: xcode, storyboard, safearea

landscape mode, the storyboard safearea leaves lots of space opposite the notch end (the right side of the attached image). is it normal?

**Rendered UI in the Simulator:**
[image]

**Applied Constraints:**

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's normal.